# Excel Macro to cut after "," and paste into another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to create a macro that will cut text from a cell after a comma, and then paste into another cell.
What i have tried to come up with

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "40000"
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 1).Range("A1:A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        " Copied Text, "
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Remaining.Text"
    ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What does your data table look like?

Comment: A mix of chars eg. "F110F1A3EER.TACA, Los, Ex d, Light , RT66." to "F110F1A3EER.TACA,"
"Los, Ex d, Light , RT66 . " gets cut off to be added to another cell that has a string of chars already

Comment: Can you add your data to your question in a nice format?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

```
Function POP_To_Delimiter(strInput As String, Optional strDelimiter As String = ",", Optional PopToDelimiter As Integer = 1) As String

Dim a() As String
a = Split(strInput, strDelimiter)
ReDim Preserve a(PopToDelimiter - 1)
POP_To_Delimiter = Trim(Join(a, strDelimiter))

End Function

Function POP_From_Delimiter(strInput As String, Optional strDelimiter As String = ",", Optional PopFromDelimiter As Integer = 1) As String

Dim a() As String
a = Split(StrReverse(strInput), strDelimiter)
ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) - PopFromDelimiter)
POP_From_Delimiter = Trim(StrReverse(Join(a, strDelimiter)))

End Function
```

Using like so

`POP_From_Delimiter("F110F1A3EER.TACA, Los, Ex d, Light , RT66.")` = Los, Ex d, Light , RT66.

and

`POP_to_Delimiter("F110F1A3EER.TACA, Los, Ex d, Light , RT66.")` = F110F1A3EER.TACA